# Ho do i use WHERE IN CLAUSE in SQL with a SET of numbers as Input Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do i select a few rows in SQL using the WHERE IN and the set of numbers is an input variable

I want to do the following

```
select datacolumn from datatable
where primarykey in (1, 2, 3)
```

I tried the following procedure but it doesn't work

```
declare @ids NVARCHAR(MAX)

select datacolumn from datatable
where primarykey in (@ids)
```

I use Sql Server 2008

Comment: IS your `@IDs` comma separated string ? If that's the case then you should follow [this blog](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). This is all you want to know about your issue.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/337704/1048425), **However**, I think the most comprehensive answer on this comes in this article [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql). which follows on from [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up).

Comment: Yeah. The top voted comment helped me out more than the marking as duplicate...